# MousePressed / MouseReleased events for user resizing (dragging) JDialog border

Tags: java, swing, resize, mouseevent, jdialog

I am trying to figure out when users have resized my JDialog, because I want to make it snap to certain size steps after that. And I need to distinguish that from resize events caused by programmatic resizes originating from elements within the dialog (which would be easy be setting a flag).

I can use the ComponentResized events from the rootPane of the dialog, and a timer to avoid getting flooded by such events (as suggested in [Java ComponentResized - Detect whether user resized the window or it was resized programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966223/java-componentresized-detect-whether-user-resized-the-window-or-it-was-resized) ).
Still this is all messy and it often results in a window that is larger than my dialog, and black areas next to the panel inside the dialog. Or I would have to have a timer that does setVisible(true) every few 100 ms. (No, pack() is not sufficient to resolve that case, it needs setVisible(true).)

I am desperatly trying **to get an event when the user releases the mouse button after dragging the dialog window frame** - that would give me a chance to react properly.

[Listen to JFrame resize events as the user drags their mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106367/listen-to-jframe-resize-events-as-the-user-drags-their-mouse) does not seem to work for me. I do not get any events when the user presses the mouse or releases it on the border of the dialog. I do get all mouse events on any panels etc, but the border seems to be out of reach.

How can I get such an event?
Or, can I query the mouse button state to avoid doing things while the user is still dragging?

Comment: The frame and its decorations are not Swing components and Swing doesn't doesn't receive those type of events. I believe you need to use "jni" or "jna' for OS level of events (I have no idea how to do it). Another option is to use an undecorated `JDialog`. Check out [Resizing Components](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) you can just register the dialog with the `ComponentResizer`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sence! I was hoping for a way to deal with it in Java. I will check the ComponentResizer, looks promising!